# jQuery Selecting dynamic content PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a series of lists with PHP. I then am trying to use jQuery to sort the list using the `.sortable()`. I kind of have it working if I only have one list. However if I have multiple lists, the jQuery is looping through both lists and only remembering the last list. I see how the `.each()` is causing this I just don't know how to work around it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
  <ul id="sortList_1">
    <li class="item_1" id="item_111">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item_2" id="item_222">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item_3" id="item_333">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

    <div class="list">
      <ul id="sortList_2">
        <li class="item_1" id="item_444">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item_2" id="item_555">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item_3" id="item_666">Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".list").each(
        function(e) {
        num = e + 1;
        $("#sortList_" + num).sortable(
            {stop:function(i) {
                serial = $("#sortList_"  + num).sortable("serialize");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "writeDB.php",
                    data: serial
                });
            }
        });    
    });
```

Comment: Isn't there an extra comma three lines from the end?

Comment: just missed that in the paste of code. I had remove opacity and cursor mods -- edited code

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/EMJax/

Comment: the .sortable works fine, it's what is getting passed to the writeDB.php. If there is one ul list - no problem. When there are 2 or more, it is always the last list that gets passed item[]=111, item[]=222 etc. The sortable always works

Comment: I'm still seeing the requests happening. But nevermind, Deefour seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code, `.sortable('serialize')` returns `null` for all lists. According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize):

> If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore.  They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number.  For example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all serialize to foo[]=1.

So, you could modify each item to have an `id` attribute of the format

```
<li class="item_1" id="item_444">Item 1</li>
```

and your script should work fine. You might consider changing the `item_` prefix to something that references the list the items are from *(ie. `list1_...` vs. `list2_...`)*, or specify the list the serialized data is for in the `data` of the ajax call.

```
data: { serial: serial, list_id: $(this).attr('id') }
```

**Edit:** You can clean up your code a bit too: http://jsfiddle.net/u425C/

Comment: you are correct, however, the loop from the each() that occurs I am only getting the id attribute from the last ul list, in the case sortList_2. That's my bad for not including the item_111 in the above example. It is how I have PHP rendering. I'll modify example

Comment: See my jsfiddle above; it generates expected ajax requests for both lists.